# How to attach Image in Annotation(Note) in Microsoft Dynamics 365 By using C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, dynamics-crm

```
if (note.FileName !=null)
    noteEntity.Attributes.Add("filename", (note.FileName));
if (note.DocumentBody != null)
    noteEntity.Attributes.Add("documentbody", Convert.ToBase64String(note.DocumentBody)); `
```

For This Code Using I will attach .txt and .doc file but I want to attach Image file on Note in Dynamics crm so How I attach image file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an attachment like so, the process is the same for all file formats. To have your file treated as an image, you need to provide the [media type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) via the `mimetype`.

```
void AttachDocument(ICrmService service, Guid entityId, String entityType, String path, String mimeType)
{
    String fileName = Path.GetFileName(path); //load the attachment file from disk

    annotation a = new annotation(); //we have to create an annotation

    a.objectid = new Lookup(entityType, entityId); //and attach to a record, e.g. contact
    a.objecttypecode = new EntityNameReference(entityType);

    a.subject = fileName;

    a.filename = fileName; //the annotation has fields which contain the attachment information
    a.mimetype = mimeType;
    a.documentbody = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path)); //crm like us to store attachments as base64 strings

    service.Create(a);
}
```